# Compile error with RcppArmadillo and R 3.1.3 and Mac Yosemite

Tags: c++, r, xcode, osx-yosemite, gfortran

I have recently installed R 3.1.3. I am using a Mac with Yosemite system and my Xcode is of version 6.2.

After I source the CPP file using  sourceCpp("try.cpp"), I get the following error. My try.cpp file has

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <math.h>
```

The error is below in R

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2'
ld: library not found for -lquadmath
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [sourceCpp_15736.so] Error 1
clang++ -arch x86_64 -ftemplate-depth-256 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include     -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include  -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include"    -fPIC  -mtune=core2 -O3    -c CAR.cpp -o CAR.o
clang++ -arch x86_64 -ftemplate-depth-256 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module - multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -   L/usr/local/lib -o sourceCpp_15736.so CAR.o -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2 -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
Error in sourceCpp("~/RA2015/Code/BYMCAR/CAR.cpp") : 
Error 1 occurred building shared library.

WARNING: The tools required to build C++ code for R were not found.

Please install Command Line Tools for XCode (or equivalent).
```

I have installed the command line tools for Xcode, my gfortran version is 4.9.0
But when I type

```
gfortran --version
```

It has the following error:

```
 gfortran: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘14.1.0
```

When I use R 3.1.2, I did not encounter this problem before!

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some finding I find a solution online.

If you have same problem with me, just type

```
curl -O http://r.research.att.com/libs/gfortran-4.8.2-darwin13.tar.bz2
sudo tar fvxz gfortran-4.8.2-darwin13.tar.bz2 -C /
```

on the terminal and sourceCpp can run smoothly.

A detailed explanation can be found at [http://www.thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/rcpp-rcpparmadillo-and-os-x-mavericks-lgfortran-and-lquadmath-error]